# decimal formatting apache poi

Tags: apache-poi, decimalformat

When I try the simple codeblock, to force two decimals I get "privledgedAction exception".  It seems that is a problem with poi openXML4J however obviously I cant be accessing that here.  How can I get the formatted value into the cell?

```
DecimalFormat df2d = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double value_d01 = cell.getNumericCellValue();
String value_d02_s = df2d.format(value_d01);
double value_d02 = Double.parseDouble(value_d02_s);
ver03_lfj.info("orig: "+value_d01+" sigDig: "+value_d02_s+" double: "+value_d02);
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue(value_d02_s);
```

Results: "orig: 0.4 sigDig: .40 double: 0.4"... the exception thrown.(yes my nomenclature is poor)

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? Have you tried upgrading to the latest? Which line gives the exception?

Comment: @Gagravarr
Thank you for taking the time.  Please see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing a cell that had been created but never assigned.  That is the source of the exception. HTH